# Class property is not widened to the inherited type

Tags: typescript

When I assign a partial value to a variable that is declared with a partial type, its type remains partial:

```
let x: { a: string, b?: string }
x = { a: "a" }
x.b  // fine, x <=> {a:string, b?:string}
```

The same with a class property:

```
class X {
  prop: { a: string, b?: string } = { a: "a" }
}
(new X).prop.b // fine, prop <=> {a:string, b?:string}
```

However, an *inherited* property doesn't seem to follow this rule and assigns the exact type instead:

```
class Y extends X {
  prop = { a: "a" }
}
(new Y).prop.b // FAIL, prop <=> {a:string}
```

[PG](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDeECGcDOYBOBLAdgcwBoIAjAfjU1zwgF8AoKCAXgWTgCIl3aGA6YiBAD0QiADNcIIowA8TAHwIU6bPiJkYKqvToBjYElSoIADQR1BABwwB7S3EQoIWtSXLPK+Ws1ZPO3enoAChwQAHdTAEpeazt+YVEJUKJYywg5RXhlT0I3TRydfUNjAE0IECgwEBwAE2MzeAsIVJ9HDi4eYNCIkujU+JEIADEAQQBJABkU2zSMpXzVPHogA)

How can this behaviour be explained?

Comment: It's [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373), I think.  `class C extends E` or `class C implements I` only *checks* that it matches `E` and `I`; it doesn't contextually type the class.

Comment: @jcalz: thanks, this appears to be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that class Y is created, it will check that prop is compatible with type `{ a: string, b?: string }` but it will then return the exact type of the object literal you passed on. which does not contain b. You can return `{ a: string, b?: string }` directly but then you loose the property names of the object literal, which would be unfortunate. so you can try:

```
((new Y).prop as { a: string, b?: string }).b
```